# Magento products showing up store front but not under categories

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

We have Magento 1.8 and everything was working fine until few days ago when we noticed products are showing up fine on the main page but for some reason do not show on any of the categories.

You can click on the product and see the details. You can search for any particular product and once again find it but nothing under categories. We have done all the usual things recommended on most forums we have searched through including reindexing and flushing the cache.

Please help - the page is maxkoldonline.com incase you would like to see the problem we are having.

NOTE: we have upgraded from 1.7 to 1.8 although we have not checked if the problem pre or post dates the upgrade.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure the products are assigned to their respective categories?  By going into a product,  go to the categories tab and make sure it has a category assigned.   There are many things that could cause this.   But this is where I would start.

Comment: Rob, thanks for your time. I have tested that and they are in the correct categories. They were working before and suddenly stopped. I have checked visibility, stock, which category they are in and so on.

When you go to the main page of the site and click on one of the products you will even see which category they belong to under the menu and when you click on that category you get a blank page instead of the products.

Comment: Then let's begin by narrowing down theme vs code base.   I would start by changing the theme to default and then viewing the category page.  Try that and let me know what happens.

Comment: I would probably bet on it's theme related.

Comment: Hi Rob, Please accept my apology for such a late reply to this topic. Yes, the I have found the problem and as it was a particular extension we have installed that caused the problem. After removing this extension the issue was resolved. Once again thanks for your time and support

Answer (score 0):

Try by enabling error display from index.php and see if any error comes on  category page.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Hi Jitendra, Thanks for your time. I have already tried that too, no errors are being displayed.